# sql most recent date

Tags: sql, date

I have two tables -- tblDividendData and tblStockPrice -- and I have been trying to construct a query to pull fields from tblDividendData along with the most recent closing price from tblStockPrice. I'm no SQL guru, so it's with some trepidation that I share my attempt here, but I've spent hours on this, seemingly trying everything, and I can't make it return correct results. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT  tblDividendData.divOrganization, 
    tblDividendData.divExDividendDate, 
    (SELECT Close 
     FROM tblStockPrice s
     WHERE Date = ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
                    FROM tblStockPrice 
                    WHERE s.Date <= tblDividendData.divExDividendDate
                    AND s.CompanyID=tblDividendData.divOrganization)) AS Close
FROM tblDividendData
```

This returns some data for the closing price field, but it's not correct: it appears that only if divExDividendDate is greater than all tblStockPrice.Date's will a tblStockPrice.Close be returned.

I'd really appreciate some help with why I can't get this working. I have set up a SQLFiddle here with the Schema and query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ae82/2/0

The query runs on SQLFiddle, but I do note that it brings Access (where I'm actually putting this together) to its knees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Try this SQL:

```
SELECT  tblDividendData.divOrganization, 
        tblDividendData.divExDividendDate, 
        (SELECT Close 
         FROM tblStockPrice s
         WHERE Date = ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
                        FROM tblStockPrice 
                        WHERE Date <= tblDividendData.divExDividendDate
                        AND CompanyID=tblDividendData.divOrganization)
         AND CompanyID=tblDividendData.divOrganization        
        ) AS Close
FROM tblDividendData
```

There were 2 problems:

1. In your subquery where you are finding the `MAX(Date)`, you used the `s.` prefix in your `WHERE` clause.  This isn't correct because that was matching against the table in the outer query.  This is probably a reason why it would be slow in Access.
2. You need to filter by `CompanyID` again once you find the `MAX(Date)`.

Comment: Thanks, David. Much appreciated! However, it still seems to make Access choke, interestingly enough, even without the 's' alias, as per your SQL. Guess I'll have to investigate a little further...

Comment: Hmm. Tried this out in Postgresql with the full data in the tables (over 4000 records in tblStockPrices) and it works a charm, so definitely Access limitation/issue.